# angular2 AOT always failing: anything wrong with this package.json?

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

Can anyone give me a working package.json to make angular2 AOT compile pass?
My package is as below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
  },
```

And after I delete all node_modules and npm install all over again, I run:

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

I get huge amount of errors.

```
Error at angular2/ng2_webpack_aot/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts:17:14: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
Error at angular2/ng2_webpack_aot/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:21:14: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
Error at angular2/ng2_webpack_aot/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:85:5: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
Error at angular2/ng2_webpack_aot/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:145:5: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Varia
.....
```

Can anyone share with me your configuration for package.json and can you compile AOT successfully?

My tsconfig-aot.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
"lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
 "files": [
    "src/app/app.module.ts",
    "src/main.ts"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

Comment: When u get this error? Run time? Npm install? N start?

Comment: show your tsconfig?

Comment: I got error when I am running the command node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to typings of `core-js` and  typescripts `es2015` lib are overlapping, try to use lib `es5` instead of `es2015`

Comment: that is the trick, why angular website is providing wrong info? Hope they can change it

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the version of typescript. Uninstall typescript version 2.0.10 and install version 2.0.3.

Comment: unfortunately, typescript 2.0.3 is having same error